# SPI EEPROM refuses to communicate, returns FF or 0 every time

Tags: spi, eeprom

I've been trying to learn SPI, using an EEPROM 25L4005. I've tinkered with it all day, read the datasheet multiple times, but still the output from the EEPROM  is FF. The data is sent to the slave correctly, but MISO doesn't seem to respond. I thought there was something wrong with the IC, so I ran a simulation in Proteus. But the problem still persists (I tried debugging using the SPI debugger in the simulator). I don't have a logic analyzer to test practically.

There is a similar EEPROM named 25LC512. Using this in the simulator works perfectly without any errors. Communication is clean.

What can be the possible problem here?

Below is the Arduino code. It works for both ICs, no need for changes, same command instructions and sequence.

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#define READ 0x03 //read command
#define WRITE 0x02 //write command
#define WREN 0x06  // write enable
 
const int csPin = 10;
const int wpPin = 9; // For this sketch you could also leave the wpPin unconnected
const int writeCycle = 10;
 
void setup(){
  pinMode(csPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(wpPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(wpPin,HIGH);
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
 
  eepromWriteEnable();// enable write enable latch bit
  digitalWrite(csPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0x60); //chip erase command
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);
  delay(8000); //max time taken for chip erase to process
 
  int intToWrite = 42;
  eepromWriteInt(4, intToWrite);
  intToWrite = -1111;
  eepromWriteInt(6, intToWrite);
 
  int intToRead = 0;
  intToRead = eepromReadInt(4);
  Serial.print("intToRead (Address = 4): ");
  Serial.println(intToRead);
  intToRead = 0;
  intToRead = eepromReadInt(6);
  Serial.print("intToRead (Address = 6): ");
  Serial.println(intToRead);
}
 
void loop(){}
 
void eepromWriteEnable(){
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(4000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(csPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(WREN); //set write enable latch
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}
 
void eepromWriteInt(int addr, int value){
  eepromWriteEnable();
  delay(100);
  // If you want to change the SPI clock speed, uncomment the following line and adjust
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(4000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(csPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(WRITE);  //write command
  SPI.transfer((byte)(addr>>16)); //1st byte of 2 byte address
  SPI.transfer((byte)(addr>>8));
  SPI.transfer((byte)(addr&0xFF)); //1nd byte of 3 byte address
  SPI.transfer((byte)(value>>16));  //2st byte of 3 byte data
  SPI.transfer((byte)(value>>8));
  SPI.transfer((byte)(value&0xFF));//3nd byte of 3 byte data
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction(); // Uncomment if you have uncommented SPI.beginTransaction()
  delay(writeCycle);
}
 
int eepromReadInt(int addr){
  byte MSB = 0;
  byte LSB = 0;
  int value = 0; 
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(4000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(csPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(READ); 
  SPI.transfer((byte)(addr>>16)); //1st byte of 3 byte address
  SPI.transfer((byte)(addr>>8));
  SPI.transfer((byte)(addr&0xFF));
  MSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //store the first byte in MSB buffer
  LSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //store the first byte in LSB buffer
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  value = (int)((MSB<<8)|LSB);
  return value;
}
```

edit: It turns out that imported parts from the components library only imports 3D model, PCB and schematic diagram, not the simulation files required. This is the reason for the simulation to fail. Practically, I might have a faulty IC. Anyways, I learned a bit about SPI just by simulatio.  No luck for practical, I guess. I will continue with the other IC.

Comment: It seems odd to me that `SPI.transfer(WREN);` is being called before the SPI peripheral is configured (`SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(4000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));`). I have to add though that I'm not familiar with Arduino code.

Comment: yes, i changed it and tried, but still no response.

Comment: 1) Have you tried to issue other commands like RDSR (read status register) or RDID (read identification), just to see if you can get a positive response from the EEPROM?
2) How are the `HOLD#` and `WP#` input pins connected?

Comment: Good to hear that you managed to solve your problem. The better way to mark your question as solved is to post your own answer (the 'edit' part of your question) and then 'accept' that answer. This would automatically flag your question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

At least the addressing is wrong.

The chip is so large it uses three address bytes, while you assume it uses two, so the chip uses the first data byte you send as last address byte, and thus sees only one data byte.

Another problem is, you never erase the flash. So writing data to any location that is not erased will just be a logical AND between previously stored data and newly written data. Which means, you can only change bits to logic zero by writing, and only an erase command will change bits back to logic one.

Comment: [arduino](https://pastebin.com/dg6skWsj) this is the link for revised code, I've written the chip erase command and also made it 3 byte addressing. And no, it still doesn't work, neither in simulator or practical. still returns FF

Comment: @chethanRaj Please use this link to edit the new code into your question, replacing the old code: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/663498/edit